# Why gpu power consumption is at 40% when gpu utilization is 100%?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

nvidia-smi shows less than 100W power consumption out of 250W while GPU-Utilization is at 100%. Shouldn't power consumption be closer to GPU Utilization? How to interpret that?

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.73       Driver Version: 410.73       CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 54%   71C    P2    90W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |    100%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 45%   64C    P2    99W / 250W |  10377MiB / 11178MiB |    100%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GPU-Util is not intended to represent the GPU's total processing abilities.

EXAMPLE:
There are two people exercising for the next 10 minutes.  One exerciser decides to walk and the other exerciser decides to run.  They are both busy so both exercisers show "Human-Util" = 100%. However, which excerciser is consuming more energy?  The runner is consuming more energy, therefore the runner might be at 90% W.  The walker may be only consuming 30% W.

If your GPU-Util shows 65%, it means 650,000 out of every 1 million clock cycles are being used, but it does not mean it is running at max capacity within each of the 650,000 clock cycles that ran.

It's the same at 100% or any other percentage.  Even though your GPU-Util shows 100% usage, it only means 1 million out of 1 million clock cycles were busy, but it may have only been using simple computations or a small amount of computations within each of the those clock cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Another explanation: power consumption value is ~0.5 seconds delayed from GPU utilization. Consecutive nvidia-smi calls show that average GPU utilization is in accordance with average power consumption.

```
$ while true ; do nvidia-smi | grep 10922MiB ; sleep .2 ; done
| 54%   71C    P2    92W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |    100%      Default |
| 54%   70C    P2    90W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |    100%      Default |
| 55%   70C    P2   254W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |    100%      Default |
| 54%   72C    P2   155W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |     99%      Default |
| 54%   70C    P2    79W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |      0%      Default |
| 54%   72C    P2   193W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |     87%      Default |
| 54%   71C    P2    97W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |    100%      Default |
| 54%   70C    P2    95W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |    100%      Default |
| 54%   71C    P2   233W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |     99%      Default |
| 54%   71C    P2    74W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |     92%      Default |
| 54%   70C    P2    78W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |      0%      Default |
| 54%   71C    P2   156W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |     77%      Default |
| 54%   71C    P2    82W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |    100%      Default |
| 54%   71C    P2   264W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |    100%      Default |
| 54%   72C    P2    82W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |     99%      Default |
| 54%   70C    P2    74W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |      6%      Default |
| 54%   70C    P2    73W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |      4%      Default |
| 54%   71C    P2   207W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |    100%      Default |
| 54%   71C    P2   109W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |    100%      Default |
| 54%   70C    P2    91W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |    100%      Default |
| 54%   70C    P2   134W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |    100%      Default |
| 54%   72C    P2   260W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |     98%      Default |
| 54%   70C    P2    79W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |     64%      Default |
| 54%   71C    P2   205W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |     92%      Default |
| 54%   71C    P2    96W / 250W |  10922MiB / 11175MiB |    100%      Default |
```