# How to inspect the actual GPU utilization across cores?

Tags: gpu

I have a program that only starts 1 thread (it's a long loop) in GPU. During the time, nvidia-smi keeps showing 100% GPU utilization. According to [Why gpu power consumption is at 40% when gpu utilization is 100%?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53324467), this is expected. However, is there a way to show the #cores that's actually running vs total #cores? This can help understand the actual utilization to help further optimize the program.

Meanwhile, the Memory utilization keeps 0%, even if I allocated 100MB in global memory and shared memory. Why is this?

The kernel is

```
__global__ void SlowKernel(double* ptr, int up_to) {
  *ptr = 0;
  __shared__ double shared_memory[1024*1024*100];
  for (int i = 0; i < up_to * 1000000; ++i) {
    shared_memory[0] += sin(i);
  }
  *ptr = shared_memory[0];
}
```

and I launched the kernel with up_to being 0 ~ 9 respectively.

I found [Why gpu power consumption is at 40% when gpu utilization is 100%?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53324467) but cannot find other useful information.